# How to inspect html code in Prestashop to link to the PHP TPL files

Tags: prestashop-1.6

It is my understanding (prob completely wrong) that the php/tpl/etc files of a Prestashop site create the html page(s) of my website (see image).

Im using Developer tools on Firefox Quantum Dev edition. I can see how my page is displayed in the code (and how it links to my webpage) but I can’t see how this relates to the addresses.tpl file (opened in Notepad++ (set to php language)) and how i work backwards to comment stuff out.

How do you work back from the html code in Prestashop to find where to alter the PHP TPL files/code?

[image]

Comment: By using a real IDE ie. [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) that allows you to search for code in whole project and lists the files that contain the code.

Comment: nice - thanks. Looks pretty technical for me but i'll def give it a go. Just by chance do you know the rough steps on how to use PHPStorm to link the webpage of my cart (using PHPStorm) to the PHP/TPL code in my site?

i link PHPStorm to my wamp server then what

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html